# Matplotlib shows no reading if the tick labels get modified

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I expect to hover my mouse over the plot and get clean data reading on the right side of the navigation bar in the automatically-generated plot window.

In my case (see code at the bottom), however, if I turn the y-axis tick labels into decibel, the y-reading in the navigation bar (bottom right corner) will disappear, like this:

[image]

Workaround: If you comment out the `#PROBLEM` code block in the code below, then the y-reading in the bottom right corner will be visible, like this:

[image]

The code I used to pack the widgets:

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
import tkinter as tk

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk as NavigationToolbar
from scipy.io import wavfile

root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(mainframe)
frame.pack()
figFrame = tk.Frame(frame)
toolFrame = tk.Frame(frame)
figFrame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
toolFrame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

# Place the figure
fig = plt.Figure()
figWidget = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=figFrame)
track = figWidget.get_tk_widget()
track.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

# Place the toolbar
toolbar = NavigationToolbar(figWidget, toolFrame)
toolbar.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

# Get data
SR, signal = wavfile.read(join(abspath(dirname(__file__)), 'y.wav'))

# Plot the signal read from wav file
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Waveform and Spectrogram of a wav file')
ax.plot(signal)
ax.set_xlabel('Sample')
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

# PROBLEM: Truncated y-readings in Toolbar
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude (dB)')
ticks = ax.get_yticks()
t1 = 20*np.log10(-ticks[(ticks < 0)])
t2 = 20*np.log10(ticks[(ticks > 0)])
t1 = [float('{:.1f}'.format(i)) for i in t1]
t2 = [float('{:.1f}'.format(i)) for i in t2]
ticks = np.concatenate((t1, [-np.inf], t2))
ax.set_yticklabels(ticks)
# PROBLEM: END


plt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

I wonder where I did wrong. My guess is that when the ticks are hacked (my way), then there will be no reading at all.... If so, then that's a pity, because I only modified the ticks not the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clear that no useful `y` coordinate can be shown when you set the ticklabels manually; maybe that becomes clearer if you consider that you could have labelled the plot with `"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"` - in that case what would the coordinate be when the mouse is halfway between `"Banana"` and `"Cherry"`?

You may however use a `FuncFormatter` to set the format of the tickslabels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import numpy as np

signal = np.sin(np.linspace(0,12,300))*.7


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Waveform and Spectrogram of a wav file')
ax.plot(signal)
ax.set_xlabel('Sample')
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude (dB)')

def fmt(x,pos=None):
    if x==0:
        return "-inf"
    else:
        return '{:.1f}'.format(20*np.log10(np.sign(x)*x))

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(fmt))


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! So as it occurred to me after posting, there is a callback for the data reading. There is only one problem in your Formatter code, the fix: if x != 0: s = 20*np.log10(np.sign(x)*x) . I have fixed it in place and will accept your answer.

Comment: I have implemented the exact code you have in the question. If you want to ask for something different, you may do so. I rerolled your edit.

Comment: "It's clear that no useful y coordinate can be shown when you set the ticklabels manually ..." While that may be how it works, that's not exactly obvious, since it's not obvious that the x-y readings in the task bar at the bottom rely on ticks. Before seeing this answer, someone could easily have imagined that they rely only on the data themselves.